# Как быстро переименовать переменные в VS C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Допустим, у меня есть много переменных с названием "a", я хочу их все переименовать в "b" во время редактирования кода. Как можно это быстро сделать?

Comment: Выделить переменную и выбрать Rename из контекстного меню (по правой кнопке мыши)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan почему не может-то? Внутри каждого блока, не говоря уже о функциях, классах и пространствах имён можно использовать одинаково названные идентификаторы разных объектов.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну да, я  про одной облати видимости.

Comment: По умолчанию, когда курсор на переменной `CTRL + R + R`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Переменная с именем **old** будет заменена на **new_var** (пример).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Find and Replace -> Quick Replace